# linq to sql string property from non-null column with default

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a LINQ to SQL class "VoucherRecord" based on a simple table.  One property "Note" is a string that represents an nvarchar(255) column, which is non-nullable and has a default value of empty string ('').

If I instantiate a VoucherRecord the initial value of the Note property is null.  If I add it using a DataContext's InsertOnSubmit method, I get a SQL error message:

> Cannot insert the value `NULL` into column `'Note'`, table `'foo.bar.tblVoucher'`; column does not allow nulls. `INSERT` fails.

Why isn't the database default kicking in?  What sort of query could bypass the default anyway?  How do I view the generated sql for this action?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **omit** the column, the value becomes the database default, but anything you insert is used instead of the default, example:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (ID, VoucherRecord) Values(34, NULL) -- Null is used
INSERT INTO MyTable (ID) Values(34) -- Default is used
```

Picture for example you have a column that defaults to anything but `NULL`, but you specifically want `NULL`...for that to ever work, whatever value you specify MUST override the default, even in the case of `NULL`.

You need to set **Auto-Sync** to `OnInsert`, **Auto Generated Value** to `true` and **Nullable** to `false` for your column to work.  [See here for a full run-down](http://www.intrepidstudios.com/blog/2009/2/6/using-default-values-in-linq-to-sql.aspx) with explanation on the Linq side.

For viewing the generated SQL, [I have to recommend LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: I see what you mean.  But if I set my Note column to AutoGenerated = true, I can't set its value, which is bad.  I get the error " Value of member 'Note' of an object of type 'VoucherRecord' changed. A member that is computed or generated by the database cannot be changed."

Comment: And if I only set AutoSync to Insert *without* setting AutoGenerated to True, I return to the original error message.  Hmm!

Comment: @Barry - Do you have Nullable set to **false** in your Linq model?

Comment: Yes, Nullable is set to false.

Comment: @Barry - Try this partial to go with the same class: `public partial class VoucherRecord { partial void OnCreated() { Note = Note ?? string.Empty; } }`  Leaving AutoGenerated set to **false**

Comment: Nick, I understand about your OnCreated suggestion, but my hope is to use this across an API I'm designing, and I really don't want to have to add lines like this for all strings.  However I think you've provided me with all the info and options that are available, so thanks!

Comment: Mentioned link is dead!